# CORS issue in lumen for POST

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, lumen

My lumen middleware has the following code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //Intercepts OPTIONS requests
    if($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
        $response = response('', 200);
    } else {
        // Pass the request to the next middleware
        $response = $next($request);
    }

    // Adds headers to the response
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Sends it
    return $response;
}
```

I can use postman to send requests and it is getting response too. When I send a post request through vue.js http method, Cross-Origin Request Blocked error is showing.

Comment: Do you use chrome? Chrome is blocking Cross Origin Requests by itself.

Comment: It happens in both chrome and firefox. I changed apache2.conf and it seems to ne working. But why it fails when doing in php??

Comment: try to us this package for [cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some changes in middleware worked for me

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $allowedDomains = array("http://localhost:8080");
    $origin = $request->server('HTTP_ORIGIN');
    if(in_array($origin, $allowedDomains)){
        //Intercepts OPTIONS requests
        if($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            $response = response('', 200);
        } else {
            // Pass the request to the next middleware
            $response = $next($request);
        }
        // Adds headers to the response
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin);
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
    }

    // Sends it
    return $response;
}
```